# Backbone updating views from fetch

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to create a real-time application and there is a collection that I am constantly fetching using setInterval. The problem I am having is that when I fetch my collection Backbone rerenders the whole collection and if I set my fetch interval too short then the events binded to the views associated with the elements in my collection don't fire the click events binded to them reliably (presumably because it was busy rerendering?). How should I structure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming based on your question that you have a single view rendering your entire collection, bound to the 'sync' event. If instead you create views to render the individual elements of your collection and, on 'sync' iterate through the models in the collection, rendering new ones and updating the views associated with models which have changed you will achieve what I think you want.

Comment: so I have to keep track of the ones I already have? Have a hash of id's and update this hash each time? So that I know which ones were removed too? Is this how it is normally done?

Comment: Should I set the model equal to the new model returned? Will that trigger a 'change' or would that be a 'reset'? Will this trigger regardless of whether the model changed?

Comment: The collection manages its set of models so unless you have cloned it a model reference should be updated with any changed data returned by the fetch() If the model has changed then it will trigger a change event from the model, which you can use to trigger an update of the associated view.

Comment: Oh okay. Final question! So I only need to check for new models and deleted models?

Comment: If you use the model's change event to update the views of the updated model then yes, that's all :D